# Package manager has died while get versionCode in android

Tags: java, android

When I get the version code like:

```
public static int getVersionCode(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return info.versionCode;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Here is the trace when it happened:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:78)
```

Comment: post the whole trace, i think context.getPackageName() is null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have similar code and it works correctly, so I don't understand why your's crashed and I am curious if you can find what caused the crash.

An alternative for you is to not look it up dynamically, but to get it from the build config.

```
public int getVersion(Context context) {
    return BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

May this will work

Answer (score -2):

try using the below code its old but I guess will work

```
public int getVersion(Context context) 
{
        try 
        {
            PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("yourpackagename", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            return pInfo.versionCode;
        } 
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```